# How to get rid of this yellow spot on my acer monitor?

Tags: display, external-display, lcd, display-settings

[image]

I didn't use anything on my display I just noticed this spot today. Can someone help me and tell me how to remove it?

Comment: It looks like burn in, or sunburn, or possibly a chemical. A towel damp with water is the best thing to use on screens. If it cleans this, good, if it doesn't, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: Can you attach the monitor to another computer to check?   Can you start from a bootable OS (bypasses your OS) to see if there is a software error?Two things to check.

Comment: @music2myear While I think this is decent advice, in my experience this is either the inside of the covering on the LCD is yellowing for the fluorescent tube in the LCD display itself has gone bad.